# Ignore insert statement with non existing table and run next statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query like this

```
INSERT NonExistingTableName(...) VALUES (...); SELECT 1;
```

I can't insert anything before VALUES so I got `Invalid object name 'NonExistingTableName'`.

Is there any way to not print error and just do next statement?

Comment: [TRY...CATCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: How it should look?

INSERT NonExistingTableName(...) VALUES (...<mark>); SELECT 1;

I can't change anything before <mark>

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, TRY/CATCH will not catch the object not found compile error unless the insert is wrapped in dynamic SQL.

Comment: So no way to handle this?

Comment: @VladyslavMozhvylo, not without dynamic SQL. I'm curious as to your use case where you try to insert into non-existing tables.

Comment: Well, tbh, it's sql injection, but table renamed/deleted, so it doesn't work already.

Answer (score 0):

Not in a simple way.  The problem is that the non-existent table is caught during the *compilation* phase of script.  If nothing compiles, nothing runs.

One option -- if you must have such code -- is dynamic SQL:

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_executesql 'INSERT NonExistingTableName(...) VALUES (...)';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH;

SELECT 1;
```

You need *both* the dynamic SQL and the `TRY`/`CATCH` block to go around the error.

Comment: I can't add any text before VALUES in INSERT

Comment: @VladyslavMozhvylo what do you mean by your comment? You need to provide more explanation.

Comment: I can't edit query before VALUES keyboard in the original query. I just can insert text after it.